# Can you measure how non-inertial a frame is at a time $t$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, inertial-frames

Consider a frame R. It is my understanding that the "non-inertiality" of R at time $t$ is characterized by:

- The acceleration of the origin of R in some inertial frame (which doesn't depend on the chosen inertial frame)
- The instanteneous rotation (which again doesn't depend of the chosen inertial frame if I'm right)

Can an observer in R measure these two, for example by dropping a ball in an endless well and comparing the measured acceleration vector with the one expected by the second law of dynamics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Get an accelerometer, a rock, a clock, and a sextant. Hold the accelerometer at the origin and measure your proper acceleration. Drop the rock at the origin and measure its (and hence your) angular velocity with the clock and the sextant.

If you want to make very precise measurements of angular velocities that are very small compared to your proper acceleration, you will need to be a bit cleverer in your experimental apparatus, for instance, by measuring the change of the plane of oscillation of a large pendulum. See: [Foucault's Pendulum experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foucault_pendulum).

Comment: Or just get one of those 6 degree of freedom accelerometers that directly measure rotation too